# Non-optimal WebGL performance with Chrome and Windows

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, webgl

As a challenge to myself, I am working on a basic minecraft remake in javascript and using the WebGL library supported by the `<canvas>` tag. I have a demo video on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0zBEyrjA3s). To make the world easily editable, I split the world geometry into chunks (16^3) areas and that means that I need draw call per rendering chunk. That is where the problem comes in. This is not a performance problem with the graphics card my Nvidia GeForce 980 does not turn on the fans even and the GPU reports only 25% utilization on half the maximum clock speed so actually a more accurate number is 12.5% utilization. The problem is in the CPU.

[image]
The `GPU Process` in the google chrome task manager is at 15% more then saturating a core in my CPU. This is what the call logger to GL says:

```
GL drawElements: [4, 7680, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 7866, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6618, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 4608, 5123, 0]
GL uniformMatrix4fv: [[object WebGLUniformLocation], false, mat4(0.9999874830245972, -0.000033332948078168556, 0.004999868106096983, 0, 0, 0.9999777674674988, 0.006666617467999458, 0, -0.0049999793991446495, -0.00666653411462903, 0.999965250492096, 0, -127.43840026855469, -129.25619506835938, -113.50281524658203, 1)]
GL uniform2fv: [[object WebGLUniformLocation], vec2(-8, -7)]
GL drawElements: [4, 7680, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6210, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 8148, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 4608, 5123, 0]
GL uniformMatrix4fv: [[object WebGLUniformLocation], false, mat4(0.9999874830245972, -0.000033332948078168556, 0.004999868106096983, 0, 0, 0.9999777674674988, 0.006666617467999458, 0, -0.0049999793991446495, -0.00666653411462903, 0.999965250492096, 0, -127.51840209960938, -129.36285400390625, -97.50337219238281, 1)]
GL uniform2fv: [[object WebGLUniformLocation], vec2(-8, -6)]
GL drawElements: [4, 7680, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 7842, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 6144, 5123, 0]
GL drawElements: [4, 4608, 5123, 0]
```

The reason I am able to have back-to-back drawElements calls is because I am using the WebGL extension `OES_vertex_array_object` so those calls aren't getting logged by the logger so you don't see them.

Iv'e herd stories of state changes being very expensive but since I'm calling a lot of `drawElements` back-to-back this shouldn't be an issue? Also I have herd that people with my type of hardware can easily do 4096 draw calls by taking into account these state changes. Maybe this is a issue with webgl itself being unoptimized from the ANGLE gl to direct3D calls that Google Chrome uses.

One more note: If I make the geometry construction size from 16^3 to 16x16x128 slashing the draw calls count by 8 I am able to run the game at a solid 60FPS if there is no world geometry being created. If there is the game is unplayable.

EDIT: some more testing... So I decided to make a minimal webgl program that turned out to be a preaty cool screen saver. Here it is:

```
<html>
<body style="margin:0px">
    <canvas id="gl" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

    </canvas>
</body>

<script type="vertex" id="vertex">
    attribute vec2 pos;

    uniform mat4 matrix;

    uniform float time;
    uniform vec2 translate;

    varying vec3 color;

    void main (){
        gl_Position = matrix * vec4(pos + translate, (sin(time) + 1.5) * -10.0, 1.0);

        color = vec3((sin(time) + 1.0) / 2.0);
    }
</script>

<script type="frag", id="frag">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec3 color;

    void main (){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertShader, "attribute vec2 pos;uniform mat4 matrix;uniform float time;uniform vec2 translate;varying vec3 color;void main(){gl_Position=matrix*vec4(pos+translate,(sin(time)+1.5)*-10.0,1.0);color=vec3((sin(time)+1.0)/2.0);}");
    gl.shaderSource(fragShader, "precision mediump float;varying vec3 color;void main(){gl_FragColor=vec4(color, 1.0);}");
    gl.compileShader(vertShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragShader);

    var shader = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shader, vertShader);
    gl.attachShader(shader, fragShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shader);
    gl.useProgram(shader);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

    var u_time = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "time");
    var u_matrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "matrix");
    var u_translate = gl.getUniformLocation(shader, "translate");

    (function (){
        var nearView = 0.1;
        var farView = 100;
        var f = 1 / Math.tan(60 / 180 * Math.PI / 2);
        var nf = nearView - farView;
        var aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_matrix, false, [
            f / aspectRatio, 0, 0, 0,
            0, f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, (farView + nearView) / nf, -1,
            0, 0, (2 * farView * nearView) / nf, 0
        ]);
    })();

    var buf = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1, -1,
         1,  1,
        -1,  1,
        -1, -1,
         1,  1,
         1, -1,
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var time = 0;

    var translations = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
        translations.push(Math.random() * 10 - 5, Math.random() * 10 - 5);
    }

    var renderLoop = function (){
        gl.clear(gl.CLEAR_COLOR_BIT | gl.CLEAR_DEPTH_BIT);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4096; i++){

            gl.uniform1f(u_time, time + i / 100);
            gl.uniform2f(u_translate, translations[i * 2], translations[i * 2 + 1])

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
    }

    window.setInterval(function (){
        time += 0.01;
    }, 10);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
</script>
```

The program draws a bunch of squares. In this case it is 4096 making that many draw calls. The performance is better then my main project but still not optimal. The gpu process uses ~13% CPU and I am somehow maintaining a sold 60 FPS. Granted, the most I am doing with this is doing a few uniform calls. My real project uses 5 shader programs and obviously handles a lot more information. I will try to write this with the api I am using to render the main game. Perhaps there is room for improvement.

Comment: Is your program running at 60FPS? If not can you show relevant rendering code and perhaps we can suggest some optimizations.

Comment: The project is running at at 30-45 FPS. The real game (the one released by mojang) runs at 400 FPS so clearly someone is doing something wrong.

Comment: I believe the problem you are facing is the notorious slow webgl uniform update performance. Try instancing using VBOs instead of uniforms.

Comment: I did. That is what the main project uses. I am only calling uniform functions when the position of the chunk changes so i need to translate the vertices and give it the right chunk coordinate to calculate lighting. The problem is these draw calls as if i render each chunk as one VBO then things run fine but generating the geometry is **really** slow but the game runs fine. So I need to split the chunk into multiple VBOs and draw calls. No uniforms happen between these extra draw calls

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. If you are using VBO instancing you should not be calling uniform functions when the position of the chunk changes. You just change the vertices value on the chunk itself and do a bufferSubData to GPU. There should be no uniform function calls. It should be just drawElements(ChunkA); drawElements(ChunkB); drawElements(ChunkC); Can you show the rendering portion of your real project?

Comment: I removed the uniform calls on my test example and the performance was the same. <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0zBEyrjA3s">If you want to see the real project right now, here it is.</a>

Comment: Since you are unwilling to show the rendering code, then the only thing i can suggest is this http://floooh.github.io/oryol/Instancing.html. It can do 300k instances on my PC at 60 fps.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating very big lists because when the game needs to create more geometry, the user wont notice any stops. I may need to create a fixed size array per chunk and use _bufferSubData_ to update anything. I was trying to avoid doing this because what if there is more complicated geometry to the point that the buffer will overflow? I will post the game code and leave a read me explaining how the rendering is done some time soon so maybe you can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

How many chunks do you have? You say each chunk is 16^3. So that's 4096 cubes or up to 49152 triangles (if by some magic you could show every face of every cube which I guess you can't)

I don't really know how to answer your question. I guess the first things to test is how much CPU does an empty program run

```js
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

I see almost no time for that one.

So, how about the minimal WebGL program

```js
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

function resize(canvas) {
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
  }
}

function render() {
  resize(gl.canvas);
  gl.clearColor(Math.random(), 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0
}
```

With just that I gets some pretty high numbers

[image]

Adding in drawing 100 spheres of 49k polys each (similar to 100 of your chunks)

```js
"use strict";
// using twgl.js because I'm lazy
    twgl.setAttributePrefix("a_");
    var m4 = twgl.m4;
    var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
    var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

    var shapes = [
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 157, 157),
    ];

    function rand(min, max) {
      return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    }

    // Shared values
    var lightWorldPosition = [1, 8, -10];
    var lightColor = [1, 1, 1, 1];
    var camera = m4.identity();
    var view = m4.identity();
    var viewProjection = m4.identity();

    var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
      min: gl.NEAREST,
      mag: gl.NEAREST,
      src: [
        255, 255, 255, 255,
        192, 192, 192, 255,
        192, 192, 192, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255,
      ],
    });
        
    var randColor = function() {
        var color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
        color[Math.random() * 3 | 0] = 1; // make at least 1 bright
        return color;
    };
                                 
    var r = function() {
      return Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    };

    var objects = [];
    var numObjects = 100;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < numObjects; ++ii) {
      var world = m4.translation([r(), r(), r()]);
      var uniforms = {
        u_lightWorldPos: lightWorldPosition,
        u_lightColor: lightColor,
        u_diffuseMult: randColor(),
        u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
        u_shininess: 50,
        u_specularFactor: 1,
        u_diffuse: tex,
        u_viewInverse: camera,
        u_world: world,
        u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world)),
        u_worldViewProjection: m4.identity(),
      };
      objects.push({
        ySpeed: rand(0.1, 0.3),
        zSpeed: rand(0.1, 0.3),
        uniforms: uniforms,
        programInfo: programInfo,
        bufferInfo: shapes[ii % shapes.length],
      });
    }

    var showRenderingArea = false;

    function render(time) {
      time *= 0.001;
      twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

      gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      var eye = [Math.cos(time) * 8, 0, Math.sin(time) * 8];
      var target = [0, 0, 0];
      var up = [0, 1, 0];

      m4.lookAt(eye, target, up, camera);
      m4.inverse(camera, view);

      var projection = m4.perspective(
          30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 100);
      m4.multiply(view, projection, viewProjection);

      
      objects.forEach(function(obj, ndx) {

        var uni = obj.uniforms;
        var world = uni.u_world;
        m4.multiply(uni.u_world, viewProjection, uni.u_worldViewProjection);

        gl.useProgram(obj.programInfo.program);
        twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, obj.programInfo, obj.bufferInfo);
        twgl.setUniforms(obj.programInfo, uni);
        twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, obj.bufferInfo);
      });
    }

        var renderContinuously = function(time) {
            render(time);
            requestAnimationFrame(renderContinuously);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(renderContinuously);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="//twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
  <script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPos;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_viewInverse;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
  v_position = (u_worldViewProjection * a_position);
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPos - (u_world * a_position).xyz;
  v_surfaceToView = (u_viewInverse[3] - (u_world * a_position)).xyz;
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

uniform vec4 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_diffuseMult;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;
uniform float u_specularFactor;

vec4 lit(float l ,float h, float m) {
  return vec4(1.0,
              abs(l),//max(l, 0.0),
              (l > 0.0) ? pow(max(0.0, h), m) : 0.0,
              1.0);
}

void main() {
  vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_diffuse, v_texCoord) * u_diffuseMult;
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(v_surfaceToView);
  vec3 halfVector = normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToView);
  vec4 litR = lit(dot(a_normal, surfaceToLight),
                    dot(a_normal, halfVector), u_shininess);
  vec4 outColor = vec4((
  u_lightColor * (diffuseColor * litR.y +
                u_specular * litR.z * u_specularFactor)).rgb,
      diffuseColor.a);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
  </script>
```

I get only slight increase in GPU process usage

[image]

So it looks like most of the time is spent in just basically handling WebGL. In other words the issue doesn't seem to be your code?

Let's try a few possible optimizations (no alpha, no antialiasing)

```js
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl", {alpha: false, antialias: false});
document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

function resize(canvas) {
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
  }
}

function render() {
  resize(gl.canvas);
  gl.clearColor(Math.random(), 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0
}
```

Seems to have gone down a tiny bit.

[image]

Looks like maybe you should [file a bug](http://crbug.com) and ask why does Chrome require 20% of 2 processes just to display a canvas

Note: In Chrome's defense, Firefox is also using about the same amount of processor power (30-40% on 1 processor).

Safari on the other hand uses just 7% for the minimal WebGL program.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in requestAnimationFrame? I recall a non-empty requestAnimationFrame/setTimeout callback with just ctx.clearRect() at 60 fps will use like 15-20% of CPU in the windows task manager even though the chrome profiler shows 97% idle time.